# codeigniter session is not storing all data

Tags: codeigniter, session

I have the following code:

```
$session_data = array(
     'user_id' => $user_id,
     'username' => $username,
     'group_id' => $group_id,
     'logged_in' => TRUE
);
$this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
```

The user_id and logged_in is stored perfectly into db, but the username and group_id is stored with an "N". The structure of the system is "modular", in my older applications following just MVC would work just fine.

Did anybody had this problem before, and if you did could you give a little bit of help ?

EDIT:
all N values are the problem where instead should be the actual value of each data

below is the user_data field from the database

```
a:5:{s:9:"user_data";

s:0:"";s:7:"user_id";N;

s:8:"username";N;

s:5:"group";N;

s:9:"logged_in";b:1;}
```

Comment: Do you want to store into DB or Session?

Comment: Can you bit more clear on your requirement?

Comment: @EdwinAlex I want to store it in DB, all settings are fine I just double checked, an still no user_id, username and group_id they're all set to "N" I'll edit the question to show you what I'm talking about

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable saving data in session.

1. Set in application/config/config.php your application to use database for saving sessions.

$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;

1. Create table in database ans also give same name to the table as it's set in config.php

   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
       session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
       ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
       user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
       last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
       user_data text NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
       KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
   );

Then, whenever you use sessions, codeigniter will relay on database and there, you can set "user_data" field with what ever you need. Perhaps, it would be good that you serialize that data ans save in "user_data" field.

Saving data in php session or cookie have certain limitations.

Comment: that is already set to TRUE and the database is created, as you can see in my edit the data i copied from db :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. This had nothing to do with CI Session Library, I had an error in my database query :(

sorry for any inconvenience that I caused